# Trouble enabling CORS through API gateway for lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Admittidly, I've never used CORS before and am not fully sure what I'm doing.

I'm trying to call a Lambda function from a website without having to go through JSONP for cross-origin requests. I tried following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) tutorial for enabling CORS through the API gateway, but it doesn't seem to work. I created a GET method, tested that it worked through Postman, and then used the enable CORS option from the action drop down menu. I'm sending the request using AJAX as follows

```
$.ajax({
        url: myEndpoint,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
    })
```

And in response I'm getting the error

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`"

Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

Comment: During preflight or during the actual request? Did you read that "However, you must rely on the back end to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers because the integration response is disabled for the proxy integration."?

Comment: That error is what is logged to the console on chrome. How do I tell if it was in preflight or during the actual request? 

That line in the documentation confused me a bit because another source I saw had some comment about not needing to edit your lambda service, though I guess that was likely wrong. So do I just need to add the CORS headers to my response in my lambda function?

Comment: If it helps, my Lambda function is receiving and processing the request, it's just the response that never makes it back to the user.

Comment: Ignore my previous two comments, adding an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to my lambda response fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry was away. Preflight can be detected since it's an OPTIONS request. I guess that the gateway handles all those correctly but rely on the backend to add CORS headers for the actual requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using proxy, then your Lambda integration response must have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.